# SQL Server - Creating a "Search library" of terms to use in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Firstly I apologise in advance if this question is a bit bare bones or has misleading/confusing terminology but I'm not sure how else to phrase it.

I have a few tables which capture the language of interactions based on a few different factors. What I would like to do is set up a sort of temporary library of language based terms that I can reference in a query so that I can search the various tables and find matches against the terms stored in the library.

I'll try and give an example:

The library might consist of the following terms:
English, German, French, Italian, Spanish

I then want to search these tables:
teacherSpokenLanguages, courseLanguages, studentLanguages

And find all the rows that contain the search terms in any particular field (and specify which field that term is being found).

I hope there's enough information to piece together my request. Is this even remotely possible? Could I create a temporary table to contain these values perhaps? I can't do anything permanent on the database, it all has to be housed within this one query and has to be non-destructive.

Comment: Basically you want to look up all columns from specified tables for a set of given values. You will need to use internal tables to retrieve list of columns and then loop through them in procedure to seek for matches.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to do, what about a simple SELECT for each table and using UNION ALL?

Comment: So these tables have multiple columns and those terms might be in any of them? That seems a strange design. You can use full text search to periodically build a catalog and search the catalog: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx